# Cordova/Javascript localStorage.setItem Only on first boot

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, storage

I am wondering if its possible to only call `localStorage.setItem` on the first boot. I just want to set up a `json` file for later use and I don't want the saved information to get wiped again because of the `localStorage.setItem` each time you restart the app. Whats the best solution for this? I have tried adding a if and checking if the save file allready existed. I couldn't get this to work and the program just crashed.

I have tried looking for other people with this same problem but I just couldn't find anyone.

This is my code:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify({          < I want
    "data":[                                           < this code
        {"id":"0", "test":"test1"},                    < only called
        {"id":"1", "test":"test2"},                    < on the first
        {"id":"2", "test":"test3"},                    < boot of my
    ]                                                  < cordova
}));                                                   < app

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

$.each( data.data , function( key, value ) {
    alert(value.test);
});
```

Does anyone have any tips for this problem? Thanks for reading/helping

Comment: I know Cordova isn't quite the same as any HTML5 stuff I'm used to, but isn't the point of localStorage that it isn't lost on a restart? (App, OS, whatever)

Comment: yeah it is my point is that i only want it to create the localstorage once and if the user rejoins it allready finds the data and doesnt overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure you want to be using local storage for this, you could check to see if the key exists before writing over it.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('data')) {
    //we haven't written the entries, write them
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify({
        "data":[  
            {"id":"0", "test":"test1"},  
            {"id":"1", "test":"test2"},  
            {"id":"2", "test":"test3"},  
        ]                         
    }));   
}
```

`getItem` will return null if the key is not found.